# Accessing Express.js request context in Mongoose models

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I am developing a REST API with my colleagues using [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) and [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/).

For some of the Mongoose `Model` `methods` and `statics` we need the `Express.js` `Request` object as an added context information source, like the authenticated user currently doing the request.

What we currently do is attach a custom property called `context` to a `Model`'s `this` context by prototyping `Mongoose`'s `Model` function.

The issue is that we ran into a nasty bug that made us realise that while with `Model.methods`, who are called on `Model` instances, it works fine.

For `Model.statics`, who are called on the `Model` "class" which is implemented as a `singleton` though, the scope is shared by the whole app meaning that if you have concurrent requests, they will override each-other's `this.context` value if you have any async behaviour in the request processing.

Now my question is the following:

- What are the best practices with `Express.js` and `Mongoose` for keeping and accessing the `request` context in `Model.statics` and `Model.methods` functions ?

Of course there are some possible hacks to simulate containment like:

1. `Function.bind()` every `Model` function to add the request context.

   -> This would mean though that if `Model.statics.a()` internally makes a call to `Model.statics.b()`, function `b()` wouldn't have a `this.context`.
2. Use the `with() {}` statement on the `request` object and call every `Model` function within that scope.

   -> Which would be pretty dirty and slow.
3. Create containers with separate scopes with the `vm` standard Node.js module.

   -> Same as (2), performance would take a big hit.

Any ideas ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4):

*Hope you are still interested in the answer*

What you really want is to mimic java's *thread local concept* which basically allows you to define something in the context of that thread.

Node is a single threaded environment and it does not provide anything like that but [domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). Domains are very useful in providing context for particular set of operations and mimicking thread local storage.

Node js domains will soon be deprecated but similar solutions like [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) are available in npm which will solve your purpose

Eg:
Create domain in the context of request

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var reqDomain = domain.create();
    reqDomain.run(next);            //here your request context is created
});
```

Now with the use of process.domain, I will be able to access 'data' bound to above created domain anywhere

```
var d = process.domain              //process.domain is always be available to you while serving the request
d.obj = {};
```